# How to change printed representation of function's derivative in sympy

Tags: sympy

In a dynamic system my base values are all functions of time, `d(t)`. I create the variable `d` using `d = Function('d')(t)` where `t = S('t')`

Obviously it's very common to have derivatives of d (rates of change like velocity etc.). However the default printing of `diff(d(t))` gives:-

```
Derivative(d(t), t)
```

and using pretty printing in ipython (for e.g.) gives a better looking version of:-

```
d/dt (d(t))
```

The functions which include the derivatives of `d(t)` are fairly long in my problems however, and I'd like the printed representation to be something like `d'(t)` or `\dot(d)(t)` (Latex).

Is this possible in sympy? I can probably workaround this using `subs` but would prefer a generic **sympy_print** function or something I could tweak.

Comment: And of course right after I post this question my browsing leads me to the mechanics module (http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/mechanics/index.html). Should this question be closed, or considered a superset question (I wonder if the general question of printed representation is still useful even if my specific use of it is a solved problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [vector printing](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/vector/api/printing.html) module that you already found is the only place where such printing is implemented in SymPy.

```
from sympy.physics.vector import dynamicsymbols
from sympy.physics.vector.printing import vpprint, vlatex
d = dynamicsymbols('d')
vpprint(d.diff())     # ḋ
vlatex(d.diff())      # '\\dot{d}'
```

The regular printers (pretty, LaTeX, etc) do not support either prime or dot notation for derivatives. Their `_print_Derivative` methods are written so that they also work for multivariable expressions, where one has to specify a variable by using some sort of d/dx notation.

It would be nice to have an option for shorter derivative notation in general.

Comment: Unfortunately after some fiddling around this both doesn't support greek letters as well as non-basic-character names (like `o_1`)

Answer (score 4):

I do this by substitution. It is horribly stupid, but it works like a charm:

```
q = Function('q')(t)
q_d = Function('\\dot{q}')(t)
```

and then substitute with

```
alias = {q.diff(t):q_d, } # and higher derivatives etc..
hd = q.diff(t).subs(alias)
```

And the output hd has a pretty dot over it's head!

As I said: this is a work-around and works, but you have to be careful in order to substitute correctly (Also for `q_d.diff(t)`, which must be `q_d2` and so on! You can have one big list with all replacements for printing and just apply it after the relevant mathematical steps.)

Comment: Note that `\d` is undefined in Python string literal. `r'\dot{q}'` or `'\\dot{q}'` is better.

Answer (score 0):

I use this tweak, you may supress writing the time dependeny everywhere, or also you may extend the existing rules with higher derivatives:

```py
from sympy import *
latexReplaceRules = {
    # r'{\left(t \right)}':r' ',
    r'\frac{d}{d t}':r'\dot',
    r'\frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}':r'\ddot',
}
def latexNew(expr,**kwargs):
    retStr = latex(expr,**kwargs)
    for _,__ in latexReplaceRules.items():
        retStr = retStr.replace(_,__)
    return retStr
init_printing(latex_printer=latexNew)

# Test
t = symbols('t',real=True)
theta = Function('theta',real=True)(t)
theta.diff(t),theta.diff(t,2)
```